# Rebus #20 is ready for your solution

Tags: rebus

This is one word that can be a noun or a verb.

[image]

Comment: You are spamming questions and getting lots of reputations! :)

Comment: Spamming questions?  No idea what that means.

Comment: Uhmmmm, look at how many questions you posted

Comment: That's called spamming?  I have a totally different definition of that.

Comment: Fine, but you still got a lot of reputation of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it

> Forage

Because

> It matches the title(foragers are ready) and it is four-rage(faces).

Comment: The plural version of the verb would've been the perfect answer, but you also got the plural doers, which is even better. :)